# node: how to read a remote config file for database?

Tags: node.js

I use that in my node

```
var database = require('./sql');
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

where sql.json contains all my database information.

However I want to use php to generate sql.json, so I have only 1 single DB config file (both for php and node)

Any idea on how to achieve that ?

Comment: `sql.json` doesn't care what it is created by. Unless you mean that it should be generated by PHP dynamically at the very moment Node is trying to read it; please specify if so. And most importantly, why should `sql.json` be generated by PHP? Is PHP calculating something that `sql.json` depends on? If you want a single DB config file, why not have `sql.json` be it, and read it with both PHP and Node?

Comment: beacuse I wnat a single PHP config for website and nodejs !
problem is require("mysql.php") will not give me the good answer
It should look like require("http://mysite/mysql.php") which is a big secuirty problem

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, use JSON for both PHP and Node, since JSON is a standard format, unlike PHP config files.

```
// Javascript
var config = require('./config.json');

// PHP
$config = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents('./config.json')));
```

Bonus - the file is not executed, neither in PHP nor JavaScript, and is thus *not* a security risk.

Unless there is something that is missing from the question, trying to read a JSON file being generated by PHP is the wrong way to go, and is pretty much the exemplar of an XY-problem.